# Computing limit of $\frac{1}{n \sin \left(\pi ^6 n\right)}$ over integers

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, sequence, discrete

I would like to compute the foillowing limit: $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\; \frac{1}{n \sin(\pi^6 n)}$$  assuming that $n$ is an integer number.

I use this code, but it does not give an answer.

```
Limit[1/(a Sin[a π^6]), a -> ∞, 
 Assumptions -> a > 0 && a ∈ Integers]
```

Comment: What you've done looks correct. `Limit[1/(IntegerPart[a] Sin[IntegerPart[a] π^6]), a -> ∞]` doesn't work either I'm afraid.

Comment: You should see a warning: `Limit::alimv "Warning: Assumptions that involve the limit variable are ignored."`

Comment: @BobHanlon I do not see this. Mathematica just gives a copy of my command.

Comment: Presumably, a version difference. I am using v12.1.1

Comment: @BobHanlon Then, how can I apply this assumption into the limit?

Comment: You can include it as you did. It just wont have any effect. Alternatively, you can use the assumptions in a `Simplify`, e.g., `Assuming[a > 0 && a \[Element] Integers, 
 Limit[Simplify[1/(a Sin[a Pi^6])], a -> Infinity]]`, however, the limit still does not exist. "Limit returns Indeterminate when it can prove the limit does not exist."

Comment: There is a similar problem:`Limit[1/x^2 Sin[1/x], x -> 0]`. It's limit does not exist and is not `∞`.

Comment: This is rather a math question than a Mathematica question (see a related topic https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24579/convergence-of-sumn3-sin2n-1/24712#24712).

Comment: By the way, this can almost certainly (in the colloquial rather than mathematical sense) be proved to not have a limit using Dirichlet's theorem on Diophantine approximation.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau: Sorry, but your claim is built on the sand.

Comment: @user64494 No idea what you are going on about. Did you try to use the Dirichlet approximation result? On pi^5? You should be able to show that the value is infinitely often larger than pi or smaller than -pi, and infinitely often either the opposite or else close to zero.

Comment: @user64494 I would encourage you not to take cheap shots and make unclear comments. If you have to say or criticise something, give specific points and don't just say "no, you're wrong". If you have something valuable to add, then do it but refrain from making vague statements. The same is true for two of your comments under the answers given!

Comment: @user64494 Stating halirutan's point a bit differently, if you insist on sniping, at least improve your aim.

Comment: In fact Assuming[] construct that depends on limit variable are also not allowed and it also warns on it.

Answer (score 9):

An appropriate tool for calculating limits of sequences over integers is `DiscreteLimit`. However `DiscreteLimit[1/(a Sin[π^6 a]), a -> ∞]` cannot compute our task. On the other hand  we can figure out that  `DiscreteLimit[a Sin[π^6 a], a -> ∞]` yields `Indeterminate`, i.e. it says that
the limit does not exist and. We can also find it  calculating discrete limes superior and limes inferior:

```
DiscreteMaxLimit[ a Sin[π^6 a], a -> ∞]
DiscreteMinLimit[ a Sin[π^6 a], a -> ∞]
```

> ```
>  ∞
> -∞
> ```

Alternatively one can find it with standard limes superior and limes inferior, e.g. `Through @ { MinLimit, MaxLimit}[1/(a Sin[π^6 a]), a -> ∞]`.
For an insight it is reasonable to plot appropriate sequence

```
DiscretePlot[ 1/(a Sin[π^6 a]), {a, 1000, 1240, 2}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

It is clearly seen that $\sin( \pi a)$ takes values between $-1$ and $1$, however $\sin(\pi^6 a)$ never equals but it can approach $0$ with a very good approximation for appropriately large integer values of $a$. E.g. we find $6$  values of $\sin(\pi^6 a)$ in the first $10^6$ natural numbers $a$ closest to $0$:

```
N[ TakeSmallestBy[ Sin[π^6 Range[10^6]], Abs, 6], 10]
```

> ```
>  {-1.694781536*^-6, 3.389563072*^-6, -5.084344608*^-6, 6.779126144*^-6, 
>   -8.47390768*^-6, 0.00001016868922}
> ```

and for our sequence they are

```
1/%
```

> ```
> {-590046.5510, 295023.2755, -196682.1837, 147511.6377,
>  -118009.3102, 98341.09183}
> ```

Comment: Hope you understand that the behavior of the first terms of a sequence says nothing about its limit at infinity.

Comment: @Artes what? 1/f limit may exist if f limit does not. See even from complex analysis: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_singularity

Answer (score 4):

```
 DiscreteLimit[(a Sin[Pi^6 a]), a -> Infinity]
                (*Indeterminate *)
    DiscretePlot[(a Sin[Pi^6 a]), {a, 1, 1000, 1}]
```

so $\lim_{n \to \infty}\; \frac{1}{n \sin(\pi^6 n)}$ divergence.

[image]

Or a method using series expansion

```
fx = Series[1/((1/x)* Sin[Pi^6 *(1/x)]), {x, 0, 1}] // Normal(* find the sereis expansion of it *)
Plot[fx, {x, -1, 1}]
Limit[fx, x -> 0]
```

Comment: Hope you understand that the behavior of the first terms of a sequence says nothing about its limit at infinity.

Comment: @user64494 But the plot gives a pretty good idea of what is happening. Proof might involve methods from Diophantine approximation (just guessing).

Comment: @Daniel Lightblau: This is rather a math question than a Mathematica question (see a related topic mathoverflow.net/questions/24579/convergence-of-sumn3-sin2n-1/…). Both the answers are primitive.

Comment: @user64494 I would not call them primitive. Rather, they are uses of computation to explore the behavior. They give one incentive for attempting to prove the limit does not exist. (I realize experimental math is not to everyone's taste.)